# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qtsql

I have a `Qt` program that makes use of `QtSql`, I have included the headers (`#include <QtSql/QtSql>`) and even ran `Run QMake` and `rebuild` however it throws the following linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(QString const&)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::open()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::QSqlDatabase()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::operator=(QSqlDatabase const&)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlError::~QSqlError()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::exec()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::prepare(QString const&)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::bindValue(QString const&, QVariant const&, QFlags<QSql::ParamTypeFlag>)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(QString const&, QSqlDatabase)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::~QSqlQuery()", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlDatabase::lastError() const", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::value(int) const", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "QSqlQuery::lastError() const", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
  "operator<<(QDebug, QSqlError const&)", referenced from:
      authcontroller::authenticate(QString const&, QString const&) in authcontroller.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I didn't perform any special steps to set up QtSql nor did I install the SQLite drivers as my understanding is that their already included with the Qt install.

Any ideas?
I'm running the latest Qt distribution

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `QT += sql` to your `.pro` file? It is not sufficient to include headers for a certain module, you should also specify its usage with the above syntax.

Comment: Yep - just did it now and it worked.  Did not fully read the QtSQL documentation :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As BaCaRoZzo pointed out, I needed to place `QT += sql` in the `.pro` file

Comment: That's the general rule for *any* module. You can check the specific module name to be declared in the documentation of any class, at the top, in the "qmake" field. See for instance [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html)